# DNS Issues: resolving amazon DNS names with special characters

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, dns

I set up an AWS VPN Endpoint last night. This is its DNS name (identifiable info removed):

```
*.cvpn-endpoint-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.prod.clientvpn.us-xxxxx-1.amazonaws.com
```

When I create an `.ovpn` file and install it in `network-manager` it won't connect. Running:

```
journalctl -u NetworkManager -b
```

returns:

```
RESOLVE: Cannot resolve host address: companyvpn.domainname.com:443 (Name or service not known)
```

I can run the `nslookup` command against any public DNS or my internal private DNS servers and it shows me the correct IP addresses. If I use the `ping` command, it doesn't know what to do with that name.

I also have Network Solutions as a DNS provider so I registered a `CNAME`. One that has non special characters in it: `companyvpn.domainname.com`  for example. It still won't resolve but again `nslookup` to the `CNAME` will pull back the canonical name which is the original `*.cvpn-endpoint-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.prod.clientvpn.us-xxxx-1.amazonaws.com` and it returns the proper IP address.

I tried pinging `companyvpn.domainname.com` from a Windows machine. It resolves just fine and showed me the canonical name and it's corresponding IP address. Why won't the resolver in Ubuntu 18.04 do that?

I put in a hostname entry in `/etc/hosts` for `companyvpn.domainname.com` and that worked fine but it's because I'm bypassing the resolution of the AWS name that has the special characters.

How can I use the DNS resolver in Ubuntu to resolve my domain name?

Comment: You will likely want to verify the security group policies for the instance allow the machine to communicate with the outside world.

Comment: asterisks are not permissible in any FQDN, and as a result, a resolver is not required to handle it. see rfc-1035: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1035

Comment: Thanks, I understand the asterisk is basically the issue, but why would amazon advertise their VPN endpoints with such DNS naming conventions? That was me just thinking out loud. I understand this is a Ubuntu forum apologies. I guess it's back to the drawing board. It works in windows dns resolution stack without issue. But systemd resolved service won't. It's one of the first times where I have seen linux doing something not as well as windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi all I found the answer to this:

" *.cvpn-endpoint-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.prod.clientvpn.us-xxxx-1.amazonaws.com "

The asterisk (*) represents  "[random-string-here]"

I put:
" vpn.cvpn-endpoint-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.prod.clientvpn.us-xxxx-1.amazonaws.com "

Then I referenced that target in my CNAME registration. It resolves perfectly.
I'm all set. Thanks all.